# question regarding W4

Tags: united-states, income-tax, form-w-4

If someone files W4 with default tax structure (no itemized deductions or allowances), can they still owe money to IRS at the end of the year if their income is > $200,000 of salary with no other taxable income?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. W4 determines how much your employer will withhold from your wages. Leaving everything at default would mean that your salary is your only taxable income, and you only take default deductions. Your employee will calculate your tax withholding based on that.

But, if your salary is >200k, I assume that you have other income (investment/capital gains, interest on your bank account), which you will have to pay taxes on.

You're probably going to have some deductible expenses (business/partnership expenses, mortgage interest, donations, college funds etc) as well.

So it is very likely, unless you're really not smart about money, that you have more to do with your taxes than just the employers' withholding.

Comment: Salary is the only income we get. Havent ventured in investments yet.

Comment: @Asdfg from my experience, even with lesser salaries, you're likely to at least get some interest income from your bank. But then again, you don't have to be precise, you're allowed to owe to the IRS on April 15, as long as its not too much (they have rules how to determine what's too much, but usually interest on savings won't bring you there).

Comment: Most of my money is in checking a/c. I do have savings a/c but the interest earned on it is less than $100 so it wont make much difference. This is just my first year with such an income and i dont have much idea abt how much tax i will end up paying so i wanted to be prepared.

Comment: @Asdfg - there are plenty of calculators on line to let you estimate your taxes. If you don't expect any other significant income, then you can leave your W4 with default values for you (they have a worksheet to calculate these values), and you'll **probably** be even with the IRS at the end of the year. If you get a $100 interest - then you just send a check for additional $35 with your return, and you're done.

Comment: +1 With 1 allowance equal to $3800, even at the 25% bracket, this means +/- $950 in withholding up or down. That's as close as you get without further tinkering. $100 in interest? That's just noise.

Answer (score 1):

There are still ways that the default values on the W4 can lead you to get a refund or owe the IRS. If there was a big delta in your paychecks, it can lead to problems. If you make 260,000 and get 26 paychecks that means each check had a gross of 10,000. Your company will withhold the same amount from each check. But If you earned a big bonus then the smaller regular paychecks may not have been withholding enough.

When bonus checks are involved the payroll office has to treat them as irregular pay to be able to make it work out. Some companies don't do this, so you may under or over pay during the year.

If you changed companies during the year, this can lead to under or over payment. The lower paying company would not know about the higher rate of pay at the other company. so at one you would under pay, and the other you would over pay. There are also social security issues with more than one employer.